# Dropdown with target links

Tags: html, css

I've got a page with a dropdown menu separate from the main Bootstrap 4.3.1 navigation for links to sections on the page. 
The dropdown HTML is:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#map-section">Map</a> linking to <section id="map-section"> or <target id="map-section">
```

The page HTML is:

```
<section id="map-section">
```

I've tried every variation of CSS I can think of or find, based on

```
    #target:before {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    height: 100px; /* fixed header height*/
    margin: -100px 0 0; /* negative fixed header height */
}
```

Tried section in place of target in the CSS as well.The link goes to the area, but the height of 100px is not taking effect.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

there is two things going on:

1. you are targetting wrong element of bootstrap from your css file.
2. if you are targetting the correct element and it is still not working you can add `!important` to css. like this:

   ```
    #target:before {
       content:"";
       display:block;
       height: 100px !important; 
       margin: -100px 0 0 !important; 
    }
   ```

try to place this code at the bottom of the css file,

`!important` attribute overrides all other options specified for this very element, and makes element to have the only value which is defined alongside the `!important`.

Comment: What do you mean, "targeting wrong element of bootstrap?" I've even tried putting the CSS on the page itself without results.